How to fix transforming an object and its gizmo together in Blender 4.0?
My issue is that I can't transform an object and its gizmo together. Does anyone know how to solve this issue (in Blender 4.0)?


You have enabled the Only Affect Origins option, you will only be able to transform the origin with this option on:

